# Is it a bad idea to create index containing field that changes frequently?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to prevent table scan on a big table where a search of a record is based on three fields, one of which may be updated.
The searching query looks like this:

```
select blabla from ttg_transaction where uti = ? and txn_type = ? and state = ?
```

The index that comes to mind (not unique, not clustered) would the three fields above. But while the first two are constant, 'state' does change during the life cycle of a record.

Is this a good reason to exclude 'state' from the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things that would make this a bad idea

- **If you have slow storage (spinning metal disks)**
- If your data types are large (TEXT/NTEXT, VARBINARY, XML, ...)
- High frequency updates.

Or a combination of these.

Assuming you have fast storage, I wouldn't worry to much. If you still have slow storage you could

- Profile the insert/update statements
- Create the index
- Profile the insert/update statements when the index is created
- Compare the results.

To profile you can use `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and/or `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`

---

To handle index fragmentation you could specify a [fill factor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/specify-fill-factor-for-an-index?view=sql-server-ver15) that makes sense for your case.

---

*If state is random text field this could interfere with your statistics as well, but you didn't specify.*

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The data type of 'state' is int so not large, the frequency is also not very high. I believe that the hardware is good but I'll have to confirm that. Thus the road is open to create an index with all three field and profile it as you suggested. Fill factor is also good to know for this index and other indexes - this a commercial application and needs to be as fast as lightning. Thanks again